# Disable page query var on a specific WordPress page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a page that has their own pagination with "?page" query var. However, page is a protected word/parameter from WordPress and it keeps redirect:

from: site.com/example/?page=2 to site.com/example/2

Does anyone knows how to disable this for a specific page?

Comment: wp uses .htaccess GET vars as /dir to create clean url for Search Engines, what you can do is, you can get query_vars to get those values

Comment: Hello @SajjadHossainSagor, I think you did not understood what is my problem. I want to disable the redirect from ?page=2 to /2.

Comment: wp internally use 'page' GET var for pagination. it will break the pagination and you can't disable it with any hook. but you can use different var name